# Linux C++: cannot run "nmcli dev list iface" when not logged in

Tags: c++, linux, network-programming, popen

I have an application in written in Qt C++ which shall gather information about the network connection.
The code to do this, is shown below:

```
class NetworkHelper {
public:
  static void networkInfo(const QString &device, QString &hwaddr, QString &hwdesc,    QString &ip, QString &ipmask, QString &gateway, QString &dhcp)
{
  FILE *fp;
  char buf[512];
  QRegularExpression re_vendor("GENERAL.VENDOR:\\s+(?<vendor>.+)");
  QRegularExpression re_product("GENERAL.PRODUCT:\\s+(?<product>.+)");
  QRegularExpression re_hwaddr("GENERAL.HWADDR:\\s+(?<hwaddr>.+)");
  QRegularExpression re_ip_gateway("ip = (?<ip>\\d+.\\d+.\\d+.\\d+)/\\d+, gw = (?<gateway>\\d+.\\d+.\\d+.\\d+)");
  QRegularExpression re_ipmask("subnet_mask = (?<ipmask>\\d+.\\d+.\\d+.\\d+)");
  QRegularExpression re_dhcp("dhcp_server_identifier = (?<dhcp>\\d+.\\d+.\\d+.\\d+)");
  QRegularExpressionMatch match;

  hwaddr = QString();
  hwdesc = QString();
  ip = QString();
  ipmask = QString();
  gateway = QString();
  dhcp = QString();

#ifdef Q_OS_LINUX
  const char *cmd = QString("nmcli dev list iface %1").arg(device).toUtf8().constData();

  if (!(fp = popen(cmd,"r")))
    return;

  while (fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), fp) != NULL)
  {
    match = re_ip_gateway.match(buf);
    if (match.hasMatch())
    {
      ip = match.captured("ip");
      gateway = match.captured("gateway");
    }
    match = re_ipmask.match(buf);
    if (match.hasMatch())
      ipmask = match.captured("ipmask");
    match = re_dhcp.match(buf);
    if (match.hasMatch())
      dhcp = match.captured("dhcp");
    match = re_vendor.match(buf);
    if (match.hasMatch())
      hwdesc = match.captured("vendor");
    match = re_product.match(buf);
    if (match.hasMatch())
      hwdesc += hwdesc.isEmpty() ? match.captured("product") : " / "+match.captured("product");
     match = re_hwaddr.match(buf);
     if (match.hasMatch())
       hwaddr = match.captured("hwaddr");
  }
  ret = pclose(fp);  
#endif
}
};
```

The application runs as autostart right after the machine has booted. The problem is that popen() returns code 139, which to my understanding means segfault, and the while-loop is not executed, so I am not able to get the network information.

If I log in and manually start the application, the above code runs fine and I get all the required network information.

Also - another part of the application starts up a HTTP server, which I am able to connect to also when the application runs as autostart, so there doesn't seem to be any network issues.

Does anyone know, how I will be able to run the popen() when the application autostarts?

Comment: NetworkManager is not always started directly at boot time. Do you have a network prerequisite in your autostart script?

Comment: No I don't. So this could be the issue? I'm using Ubuntu. Do you more information about what I would need in my script?

Comment: I tried to add 'sudo service network-manager start' to my autostart script, but in this case my http server doesn't start and hence I cannot connect to the application at all. Any ideas how I proceed?

Comment: Can anyone please give a hint what I would need to add to my austostart script in order to ensure that NetworkManager is started?

Comment: just to clarify. If my application is running in the background and I log in to machine or do a ssh, then popen("nmcli dev list iface eth0", "r") works fine and gives return code 0. If I log out or ends the ssh session, then the popen() command does not work and gives return code 139.

Answer (score 0):

Found out that my application started up before the network manager (or something like that - not fully sure why I saw the above behaviour as I was able to connect to the http server started by application but not able to run nmcli command).

In my autostart script I added the condition not to start the application before online connectivity is established, which solved my problem